# WPF: Unable to hit breakpoint on an inner class in my viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, visual-studio-2015

I am currently working on a project that is requiring drag and drop functionality.

I am using the GongSolutions.DragDrop nuget package in order to simplify my solution. The library allows you to bind a "dd:DragDrop.DropHandler" attribute on the xaml to a class that implements the IDropTarget interface.

Inside my viewmodel I have created an inner class to implement this and have bounded to it as such, the functionality works but for some reason I am unable to hit any breakpoints within this inner class? I was able to hit all breakpoints when I had the viewmodel itself inherit from it but I decided to implement an innner class so I can have multiple drophandlers within it.

The following is the code with details removed for simplicity as there is a lot of code, breakpoints work inside the MainViewModel but when you set a breakpoint within ModuleItemsListDropHandler it will not hit the breakpoint at all

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ModuleItem> _moduleItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ModuleItem> ModuleItems
    {
        get { return _moduleItems; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<ModuleItem> _moduleTiles;
    public ObservableCollection<ModuleItem> ModuleTiles
    {
        get { return _moduleTiles; }
    }

    //breakpoints work within this method
    public void addToList(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //removed for simplicity

    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //removed for simplicity

    }



    //Class that will not let me hit breakpoints that are set
    class ModuleItemsListDropHandler : IDropTarget
    {

        void IDropTarget.DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
        {
            //functionality during drag over
        }

        void IDropTarget.Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
        {
               //functionality for drop
        }


    }
}
```

I am currently using the community edition of VS 2015

Comment: [Please read this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Whatever method you're putting the breakpoint in probably isn't getting called. How are you binding anything in XAML to an instance of ModuleItemsListDropHandler? It's a private class. It's remarkable that you included the `ModuleItems` and `ModuleTiles` properties, but excluded so much that's obviously relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that it was a private class, the Default drop handler is almost identical to mine so It was hard not to notice the error. I ended up creating a property to hold an instance of the class since It was not allowing binding to the class even when it was public and now it works, if you could post that as an answer I will select it as the best one

Comment: Awesome, that was easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unlikely that you have a class that just doesn't work with the debugger. Best bet is that the method isn't really being called. A quick call to `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` or even `MessageBox.Show()` can answer that question without much trouble.

However. Is this really how your drop handler class is defined?

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ...

    class ModuleItemsListDropHandler : IDropTarget
    {
```

If so, that's a private class, so I wonder how you're binding an instance of it to anything in the XAML. You can't declare a non-private property with that return type, for example. You *could* be returning it as `IDropTarget` or as `Object` from something, of course.

Incidentally, classes (or anything defined directly in a namespace) ordinarily default to `internal` access, not `private`, but a child class, like a class member, defaults to `private`.